# Cell.getFillForegroundColorColor() in apache poi results null all time

Tags: java, apache-poi

i have excel file which having some cell coloured with yellow background and
green foregroundcolor.When i m getting this getFillForegroundColorColor it is giving me none color.

```
for(Row row:new_sheet)
      {
          for(Cell c:row)
          {
              CellStyle cellStyle = c.getCellStyle(); // cellStyle is always not-null
              ExtendedColor extendedColor = (ExtendedColor)cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor(); // extendedColor may be null
              String color = "none";
              if (extendedColor != null) {
                  byte[] bytes = extendedColor.getRGB();
                  color = Arrays.toString(bytes);
              }
              System.out.println("Cell " + c.getAddress() + " of type " + c.getCellType() + " has color " + color);
          }
      }
```

output:

```
Cell A1 of type 1 has color none
Cell B1 of type 1 has color none
Cell C1 of type 1 has color none
Cell D1 of type 1 has color none
Cell E1 of type 1 has color none
Cell F1 of type 1 has color none
Cell H1 of type 1 has color none
Cell A2 of type 1 has color none
Cell B2 of type 1 has color none
Cell C2 of type 1 has color none
Cell D2 of type 1 has color none
Cell E2 of type 1 has color none
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the Fill Background colour instead?

Comment: yes its giving me 64 value

Comment: Is 64 the right indexed colour?

Comment: no i have yellow colour and green colour for some cells but it gives me 64 value to all cell . 64 is by default colour value. i would like to tell excel which is having coloured cell firstly it has some records and then i have applied filter and gave colour to some cell. is it possible that it won't be applicable to updated excel.or it requires already coloured values cell